# make text bold runtime

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout to bind view to viewmodel.

I have my view as

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td  data-bind ="text: ConcenatedData"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

My view model makes ajax call and binds data to observable array

```
function showData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "../Service/EmpData",
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (allData) {
            var Data = $.map(allitems, function (item) {
                return new EmpList(item);
            });
            self.EmployeeData(Data);
        }
    });
}

function EmpList(items) {
    this.EmpName = ko.observable(data.EmpName);
    this.EmpId = ko.observable(data.EmpId);
    this.ConcenatedData = ko.observable(data.ConcenatedData);
}
```

I get Data  in my observable as `<temp>Is this Emp required</temp>in our company`

So i want to make text bold between tag  `<temp> and </temp>.`So output will be **Is this Emp required** in our company`

How to achieve this?

**Update**

I have created fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/67/) I want the text between  tag  `<temp> and </temp>.` to be bold.

Comment: Modern browsers will get this css rule: `temp{font-weight: bold;}`

Comment: @Cherniv can you please show me how?

Comment: He just did, haha xD  You just put the code he gave in a pair of `<style>` tags like any other CSS. Or you could put it in the `<temp>` selector if you're able to by doing `<temp style="font-weight:bold">`

Comment: just add this line in the `head` of your page: `<style>temp{font-weight: bold;}</style>`

Comment: Wait you know knockout.js but not simple CSS?

Comment: @user1477388 unfortunately i am not great at both :(

Comment: @Cherniv didnt get exactly where to put. Sorry about it.

Comment: You put `<style>temp{font-weight: bold;}</style>` in between your `<head>` and your `</head>`.

Comment: @user1477388 i dont need to put anything in my td tag?

Comment: No, Happy.  Please try and see and let us know if you have any issues.

Comment: @user1477388 When i put in my head tag the visual studio complains that "selector matches unknown element temp". Cant understood how can i put it in head tag

Comment: That's because `<temp>` isn't a real tag.  Try using `<span>` in place of it and change your CSS to `span {font-weight: bold;}`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34186/discussion-between-happy-and-user1477388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution without having to change span (even though you should change to span since it's a real tag and `<temp>` is not):

http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/69/

Change:

```
<td data-bind="text: display"></td>
```

To:

```
<td data-bind="html: display"></td>
```

**Edit:**

Update to include `<val>` - http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/70/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working fiddle: http://bit.ly/172W1TG

- Change `<temp>` to `<span>`
- Change `text:` to `html:`
- Add `.makeBold` the the parent `<tr>`
- Add this css

  .makeBold span {
      font-weight: bold;
      border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  }

Comment: many thanks for your solution but i need to accept another solution as he helped me a lot.  I upvoted for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is to use the knockout.js custom binding for it, which replaces the `<temp>` and `<val>` tags dynamically to `<span>` and `"`. This might be helpful if you want to do some more advanced custom bindings in the future with knockout.js

The custom binding could look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.boldText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        val = valueAccessor().replace('<temp>', '<span class="makeBold">').replace('</temp>', '</span>').replace('<val>', '"').replace('</val>', '"');

        element.innerHTML = val;
    }
};
```

And then you would do the following binding:

```
<td data-bind="boldText: display"></td><td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

See a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PC54y/1/